# Split string into pair

Tags: python

What would be the best/easiest way to split a string into pair of word ?

Ex:
string = "This is a string"

Output:
["This is", "is a", "a string"]

Comment: Split by spaces then join every 2 words with a space: `words = "This is a string".split()` and then `[c + " " + n for c, n in zip(words, words[1:])]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a, b = itertools.tee('this is a string'.split());
>>> next(b, None)
>>> [' '.join(words) for words in zip(a, b)]
['this is', 'is a', 'a string']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string_list = string.split()
result = [f'{string_list[i] string_list[i+1]}' for i in range(len(string_list) - 1)]
```

Comment: Using `range(len())` is a very non-pythonic way of doing this. Woodford's solution using `itertools` is much better.

Comment: I suggest using `enumerate` with this answer

Comment: I am not aware of this, why is it so, please enlighten me? And then, the comment by Boris on the main question would be better. Use of vanilla python, without any imports.

`result = [f'{j} {k}' for j, k in zip(string_list, string_list[1:])]`

Answer (score 0):

```py
words = str.split()
output = []

i = 1
while i < len(words):
    cur_word = words[i]
    prev_word = words[i - 1]
    
    output.append(f"{prev_word} {cur_word}")
    
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`zip` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), with its first argument the whole list of words and its second the list of words without the first word. Since `zip` aggregates elements from each of the iterables, this will connect each word with its next in the list:

```py
string = "This is a string"
zipped_lst = zip(string.split(), string.split()[1:])
print(list(zipped_lst))
```

This outputs

```
[('This', 'is'), ('is', 'a'), ('a', 'string')]
```